# How to redirect URL in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect URL in .htaccess file

**From**

```
wetch?v=wo4sdnjfiro
```

**to**

```
video/wo4sdnjfiro
```

Thanks for help!

Updtae!

```
RewriteRule ^watch$ view.php [QSA,L]
```

How can I get the To url. Thanks Sir Jim W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=(.*)
 RewriteRule watch$ video/%1 [R=301,L]
```

You can see that the `RewriteCond` captures the regex group `(.*)` and then uses it in the `RewriteRule` as `%1`

Comment: Works Sir. Thank's

Comment: Sir Please help... How to make this function like my request above?
This My Code in .Htaccess..
----
RewriteRule ^watch$ view.php [QSA,L]
----
to work like this url: domain.com/video/wo4sdnjfiro

Comment: @user7395929 you should edit the original question and put the code in an UPDATE section.  Why didn't you use the code in my answer?

Comment: Sorry. I use my friend's code, the question above is different from the web that I used first. Okay sir, I will update

Comment: Ok, if it's a different question you really need to post a fresh question, and make sure you explain everything please.  I don't actually follow what's going on, but if you post it fresh it should make sense by itself.

Comment: Thanks Mr Jim.
Follow My New Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278886/change-the-url-in-htaccess